# Python: how to distinguish unavailable DNS server from non-existing address

Tags: python, dns

Name resolution may fail because there is no ip associated with the hostname, or because the DNS server cannot be reached. Unfortunately, Python's `socket.create_connection` and `socket.gethostbyname` functions seem to raise the same error in both situations:

```
$ python3 -c 'import socket; socket.create_connection(("www.google.com_bar", 80))'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 491, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 530, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

$ python3 -c 'import socket; socket.gethostbyname("www.google_bar.com")'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname

$ sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf # point to non-existing nameserver

$ python3 -c 'import socket; socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 80))'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 491, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 530, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

$ python3 -c 'import socket; socket.gethostbyname("www.google.com")'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
```

Is there any way to distinguish these two cases that does not require me to perform a second lookup for a "known-good" hostname?

The solution should work under Linux.

Comment: Have you considered looking at the error's `args` attribute?

Comment: @jonrsharpe they are included above, e.g. in the last case `args` is `(-5, 'No address associated with hostname')`.

Comment: @Nikratio The question of jonsharpe was an answer - if you use the value of `args` attribute, you have something, what allows you to distinquish different types of DNS problem.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky as you can see above, the contents of `args` are the same in both cases.

Comment: @Nikratio Sorry, you are right, now I understand your problem better. No idea what to advice.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky I made the same error and am similarly stuck. It seems there is no way to distinguish between the two cases; at least, not from outside `socket`.

Comment: You could try specifically connecting to google.com (or your own website!); if that works but your desired endpoint doesn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [dnslib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dnslib) library client to make the DNS request yourself. The client provides dig like functionality that can indicate if an address fails to resolve (`NXDOMAIN`) compared to just failing to resolve (which unfortunately just blocks - see patch below).

You use it like so:

```
from dnslib import DNSRecord, RCODE

# I have dnsmasq running locally, so I can make requests to localhost.
# You need to find the address of the DNS server.
# The /etc/resolv.conf file is quite easily parsed, so you can just do that.
DNS_SERVER = "127.0.0.1"

query = DNSRecord.question("google.com")
response = DNSRecord.parse(query.send(DNS_SERVER, 53, False))
print RCODE[response.header.rcode]  # prints 'NOERROR'

query = DNSRecord.question("google.com_bar")
response = DNSRecord.parse(query.send(DNS_SERVER, 53, False))
print RCODE[response.header.rcode]  # prints 'NXDOMAIN'

# To avoid making the DNS request again when using the socket
# you can get the resolved IP address from the response.
```

The problem comes when making a connection to a non existant DNS Server. Every time I have tried this the request just hangs. (When I make the same requests on the command line, using something like netcat, the request also just hangs. I may be picking random IPs poorly and suffering from firewalls that just drop the packets)

Anyway you can alter the source code to add a timeout. You can view the relevant method in the source [here](https://bitbucket.org/paulc/dnslib/src/e6b94b75bf123b754eb542f3d4992d477233a305/dnslib/dns.py?at=default#cl-345) (also mirrored on [github](https://github.com/paulchakravarti/dnslib)). What I changed was:

```
--- a/dns.py
+++ b/dns.py
@@ -357,6 +357,7 @@
             response = response[2:]
         else:
             sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
+            sock.settimeout(10)
             sock.sendto(self.pack(),(dest,port))
             response,server = sock.recvfrom(8192)
             sock.close()
```

After doing this the DNS request timed out.